# Transforming List to Seq of tuples of attributes in Scala?

Tags: scala

What would be the best way to transform `List[Foo]` into `Seq[(String, String)]`, considering that `Foo` is a Java interface like this:

```
public interface Foo {
    Long getKey();
    String getValue();
}
```

Comment: Where would the second String come from? Should Long be converted to String and be the first item in a tuple?

Comment: Exactly, @JacekLaskowski.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform them with `map`.

```
class Bar extends Foo{
     | def getKey = 0
     | def getValue = ""
     | }
defined class Bar

scala> val bar = new Bar
bar: Bar = Bar@7fe69211       

scala> val foos = Seq(bar, bar, bar)
foos: Seq[Bar] = List(Bar@7fe69211, Bar@7fe69211, Bar@7fe69211)

scala> foos.map(foo => (foo.getKey.toString, foo.getValue))
res0: Seq[(String, String)] = List((0,""), (0,""), (0,""))
```